# Как можно проверить правильность раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-поиск

Сегодня на Яндексе увидел такую фишку, когда начинаешь вводить пароль, используя русскую раскладку клавиатуры, появляется красная надпись:

> **Смените раскладку**.

Как это можно реализовать? Как можно проверить правильность раскладки клавиатуры?

[image: Неправильная раскладка клавиатуры]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Довольно просто проверить вводимую строку на вхождение символов русского алфавита с помощью regexp.

Comment: А конкретнее можете написать?

Comment: Так попробуйте:

    $('#txt').keyup(function(e){   
        if($(this).val().match(/([а-яА-Я]+)/)){
            alert('Смените раскладку');
        }
    });

Comment: Так тоже не совсем правильно.  `[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]` будет также ловить и букву ё, которая в Unicode идёт в другом блоке.